# Alloy weird behavior?

Tags: alloy

```
abstract sig S {}
one sig S1, S2 in S {}
fact {S1 != S2}
run {-1 < S1.(S2 -> 1)}
```

When I open the instance, I got

```
integers={-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
univ={-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, S$0, S$1}
Int={-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
seq/Int={0, 1, 2, 3}
String={}
none={}
this/S={S$0, S$1}
this/S1={S$1}
this/S2={S$0}
```

From the evaluator,

> (1)    S1.(S2 -> 1) evaluate to {}
>
> (2)    none = S1.(S2 -> 1) evaluate to true
>
> (3)    -1 < S1.(S2 -> 1) evaluate to true // Why is an integer less
>   than an empty set?
>
> (4)    -1 < none gives type error // This looks good but give (3), why
>   this gives type error?
>
> (5)    0 <= S1.(S2->1) evaluate to true
>
> (6)    0 >= S1.(S2->1) evaluate to true
>
> (7)    0 = S1.(S2->1) evaluate to false // Given (5) (6), it seems
>   S1.(S2->1) evaluate to 0, but it's not.
>
> (8)    0 = none evaluate to false
>
> (9)    0 <= none gives type error // (8) (9) seem to be interesting as
>   "=" is not interpreted as integer comparison.

Could anyone explain why (1) - (9) happen?  Is there a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) This should be obvious why: it's a relational join and `S1` is not the same as `S2`

(2) `none` evaluates to empty set, so given (1) it makes sense that `none = S1.(S2->1)`

(3) There is no type error there because the type of `-1` is `int`, and the type of `S1.(S2->1)` is `S.(S->int)` which is `int`.  The question is only why `-1` is less than some integer-typed expression that evaluates to an empty set.  First of all, the expression `-1 < S1.(S2->1)` has to evaluate to something (i.e., can't throw an exception like it might in a programming language).  Further, that's a boolean expression, so it has to evaluate to either `true` or `false`.  So what Alloy does, in order to evaluate the `<` operator, it has to convert both sides to a single (scalar) integer, even though both sides are in fact sets of integers (everything is a set/relation in Alloy), and it does so by summing up all atoms that are present in each set.  So **just for the sake of arithmetic comparisons**, `S1.(S2->1)` evaluates to `0`.

(4) It should be clear now that `-1 < none` is indeed a type error, because the type of the left-hand side is `int` and the type of the right-hand side is `none`

(5), (6) Same explanation as for (3)

(7) `0 = S1.(S2->1)` is false because `=` is **always** a set comparison, not an integer comparison.  If you try something like `1 + 2 = 3` you'll get `false`, because the set {1, 2} is not {3}.

(8) Same thing, `=` is a set comparison

(9) Same explanation is for (4)